How to select line of text without space between lines if the line-height value is big?
How can I select line of text with big line-height property value? Selecting only the text and not the spaces between the lines. For instance,


p {
  line-height: 6;
  font-size: 18px;
}
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, ratione saepe? Rerum, autem! Nulla consequatur, optio praesentium aliquid modi, beatae fugiat asperiores suscipit enim excepturi hic, magnam fugit? Voluptates, fuga?
</p>



The code snippet above will have selection indication (blue/gray background) on the whole line:


Rather I want it to select only the text without the space between the lines. This would be the result I want to achieve:

Just as in the following snippet, I want to achieve the effect of selecting two paragraph (as follows) but in one p tag.


p {
  line-height: 1.45;
  font-size: 18px;
}
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
</p>
<p>
  Rerum, autem! Nulla consequatur, optio praesentium...
</p>




There are details which I tried to indicate needed sorting out in the staging ground but haven't been. Please explain how the height of the required shaded bit is decided. The image you show of the desired result shows differing shaded heights and I can't see at all what will have decided those.

This is also browser dependent. You seem to be using a browser with the Blink engine whereas Firefox, with the Gecko engine, does it the way you want. I have not tested the WebKit engine which is used in Safari.

Adding an extra span where you reset the line-height and use a mask seems to work. I am not sure how reliable is this solution.


p {
  line-height: 6;
  font-size: 18px;
}

p span {
   line-height: initial;
   mask: conic-gradient(#000 0 0);
}
<p>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, ratione saepe? Rerum, autem! Nulla consequatur, optio praesentium aliquid modi, beatae fugiat asperiores suscipit enim excepturi hic, magnam fugit? Voluptates, fuga?</span>
</p>




I get the reset of the line-height, but what does the mask do? It works, but it seems weird to use a conic-gradient()? Did you copy this solution from somewhere else? In that case please include the source.

@KIKOSoftware It's my solution

I don't think it's good for later developments and readability of code. And mask won't be a good option since selection on android still show offset selection indicators.

Okay, well in that case you must understand what it does, but you didn't explain it. You just say it seems to work. Can you please explain what this code does?

@KIKOSoftware I'm yet to understand CSS clearly but I know it isn't actually using the system's default selection indications. Especially in chrome on android. There is two offset selection indicators (relative to the selected text) in google chrome. But it works fine in Firefox.

If you want to do this with CSS only the the answer is NO.
You can achieve this by having different html elements.
Only a small subset of CSS properties can be used in a rule using ::selection in its selector: color, background, background-color and text-shadow.
Note that, in particular, background-image is ignored, like any other property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/::selection

The OP hasn't specified that only CSS can be used as a solution, and they have tagged HTML, so how would you change the HTML so that what they want can be achieved?

Yes, you're right.  The solution is not available using CSS but can be achieved by HTML.  In HTML we can different element <div> or <span> or something else.  Hence, I mentioned only CSS solution is not viable.

sorry for the confusion, I was not going for ::selection pseudo

Anyway, the solution is with different tags not line-height.
